# React Native + react-native-router-flux: hideNavBar makes all components disappear

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

In React Native using react-native-router-flux, when I try to hide the nav bar all the components disappear.
Here is my code :

```
<Router>
   <Stack key="root" >
      <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login" initial={true} hideNavBar={true}/>
      <Scene key="signup" component={Signup} title="Signup" />
   </Stack>
</Router>
```

I tried other alternative solutions but still have the same problem.
[image]

Here is how it looks without using the hideNavBar property.
[image]

Comment: can you share an app screenshot after removing the `hideNavBar` prop?

Comment: can you try adding `hideNavBar` to your `Stack`?

Comment: Adding the hideNavBar to the stack gives the same result. :/

Comment: i see. adding the `hideNavBar` prop to either the `Scene` or the `Stack` works for me. may i know what version of `react-native-router-flux` you are using? i'll try replicating this on my end to test.

Comment: @kenmistry, I am working with the react-native-router-flux version ^4.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after looking through your snack, i realise that the parent `<View />` component under `App.js` seem to be causing the issue without any error flags. by removing it, the components have reappeared. i would suggest that you add the css styling to each `Scene` separately, which would also give you granular control. or you probably have to rework your components in order to have a base styling theme. this is the updated [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kenmistry/e-learning-school-example).

[image]

using `^4.2.0` of `react-native-router-flux`, i am able to replicate your above example without any issue of components disappearing upon setting `hideNavBar` prop to true. as i do not have the code to your components, i am using a basic `View` with a `Button` for navigating between the stack's scenes.

i have included a snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kenmistry/react-native-router-flux-example-2) so that you can take a look and see what went wrong. :)

Comment: Thank you @kenmistry for answering, this is what I did in first but id doesn't work. So here is my hole project: https://snack.expo.io/@ameurbilel/e-learning-school

Comment: @Bilel the `View` component seems to be causing the issue. you can take a look at my updated snack after i've looked through yours.

Comment: I see no changes in your snack. Also I couldn't find what "View" you are talking about.

Comment: @Bilel not sure what went wrong. can you take another look at it? i replaced `<View>` with `<Fragment>`.

Comment: using the <Fragment> instead of <View> worked perfectly, couldn't figure out why this happen yet. But anyway thank you very much. :)